# Is there a way to check if a CD-R is finalized in Java?

Tags: java, cd-rom

I am writing a program, and one of the requirements is that data can only be accepted from a CD-R that has been finalized. I cannot for the life of me figure out how to accomplish this check in Java. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Related: [How to find out when a disc (DVD) has been written/burned?](http://superuser.com/q/559031/305088)

Comment: This isn't really what I was talking about, I do not really care WHEN the disk was burnt, I only care to check if it has been finalized so that data cannot be added onto it at a later date. Thanks for the related psot though.

Answer (score 1):

When a CD is finalized, it reports zero free file space.

Since Java 1.6, the [File](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html) class has a getFreeSpace method.

When I tried this code on my Windows C: drive, it returned 403,547,947,008.

```
package com.ggl.testing;

import java.io.File;

public class GetFreeSpace {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        File file = new File("C:");
        System.out.println(file.getFreeSpace());
    }

}
```

Try it on your CD drive, and see if it returns zero or a number, for a finalized CD or a not finalized CD, respectively.

Comment: Im about to try it, I'll let you know how it goes! Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately both finalized CDs and non-finalized CDS report a disk space remaiing of zero, so this method will not work.